# Unable to upload image in spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have developed a springboot application using react as frontend to upload image into a folder.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public ResponseEntity<?> uploadImage(@RequestParam("user") String user, @RequestParam("image") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------------------");
        this.process(IOUtils.toByteArray(file.getInputStream()), user, file.getOriginalFilename().substring(file.getOriginalFilename().lastIndexOf(".")));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<>("Uploaded", HttpStatus.OK);//userService.uploadImageFile(user, file);
}


@Async
public void process(byte[] bs, String user, String ext) throws IOException {

    String fName = user.substring(0, user.lastIndexOf("@")).concat(ext);
    // Full path
    String filePath = path + File.separator + fName;

    System.out.println(fName + " and " + filePath);

    File f = new File(path);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
    }

    File convertedFile = new File(filePath);

    FileOutputStream fOS = new FileOutputStream(convertedFile);
    System.out.println("-----Started------");
    
    fOS.write(bs);
    fOS.close();
    System.out.println("-----closed------");
}
```

I am trying to upload an image into a folder.
While using file.getInputStream to upload the image multipartfile to a folder, I am getting below error

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver[0;39m: Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items
java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete D:\JS Projects\myapp\BackEnd\UserLoginSignUp\images\work\Tomcat-2\localhost\ROOT\upload_d31827cc_51e6_4901_b60e_6afdd0ee8a99_00000004.tmp
at org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.delete(DiskFileItem.java:431)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationPart.delete(ApplicationPart.java:53)
at org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:134)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.cleanupMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1251)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1108)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:965)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:555)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:623)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:209)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:178)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:153)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:926)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1791)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

what could be the reasons for above errors and exceptions. and how we can fix the above issues?

Comment: If the `IOUtils` class you are using is from `commons-io`, `toByteArray` doesn't close the `InputStream`, that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!!
Yeah it's correct..

once we open the InputStream and OutputStream those needs to be closed.
otherwise it'll give error.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `Files.copy()`, it will save a lot of work for you.

```java
public void saveFile(String directory, MultipartFile file) {
    if (file.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }

    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    if (Objects.isNull(fileName) || fileName.isEmpty()) {
        fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
    try {
        Path path = Paths.get(directory);
        Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), path.resolve(fileName));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Even after using File.copy(), I am still getting some errors and warnings.

as shown below 


`java.nio.file.FileSystemException: images\abhishananda.jpg: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`  and

`org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver[0;39m: Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items`
`java.io.UncheckedIOException: Cannot delete D:\JS Projects\myapp\BackEnd\UserLoginSignUp\images\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_0d042c86_7c45_489e_8c33_f73a99b86af1_00000012.tmp
`

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!!


once we open the InputStream and OutputStream those needs to be closed.
otherwise it'll give error.

Answer (score 0):

MultipartFile class provides a dedicated method to transfer the received file to any destination. You can implement it like this:

```
public void uploadFile(String uploadDirectory, String uploadedFileName, MultipartFile receivedFile) throws IOException {
    log.info("File received {}", receivedFile.getOriginalFilename());

    // create all needed directories (if not exist)
    Files.createDirectories(new File(uploadDirectory).toPath());

    // transfer received file (copy or move depending on location)
    receivedFile.transferTo(new File(uploadDirectory + uploadedFileName).toPath());

    log.info("File uploaded in {} as {}", uploadDirectory, uploadedFileName);
}
```

Please note: do not call this code asynchronously. Otherwise Tomcat will try to delete the temporary file even before it has been transferred.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping!!


once we open the InputStream and OutputStream those needs to be closed.
otherwise it'll give error.